# How do I change the background color in response to the build status of running an Apache Ant script?

Tags: ant, windows-xp

Depending on the build exit status, i would like to change the background color to green or red.

How do i achieve this with Apache Ant and windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use the color command:

http://www.computerhope.com/color.htm

and execute it from an Ant script using [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

```
<exec dir="." executable="color" os="Windows NT">
  <arg line="1"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: The color command indeed can change the background. But how do i integrate that into the build return result? 

I.e. BUILD SUCCESSFUL, then i can run 'color 2F'

Comment: Hmm, I thought that would be the easy part, take a look at the Sound task in Ant, you should be able to hack that, will take a look myself also...